# Calling A Function Before NSTimer Fires

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an NSTimer which fires after 1 minutes but I want to display a warning when the remaining time till fire is 10 seconds. How do I present an alert when the remaining time is 10 seconds?

Comment: check in Timer , `timer.timeInterval` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Declare a counter with value 0.
- Set the timer to fire **repeating** after 10 seconds.
- When the timer fires increment the counter.

  - If the counter is 5 show the alert.
  - If the counter is 6 destroy the timer and do what you are going to do when the timer fires.